# mediaelement.js / html5 video keeps on loading forever when advancing too much or going back too much

Tags: javascript, html5-video, mediaelement.js

I am having a problem with mediaelement.js with my own MP4/M4V files. When I click the seekbar cursor and drag it forward, the movie advances with no problem. But if I click too far forward or backward, the player enters a catatonic state and keeps on loading forever.

The problem occurs in both Chrome (catatonic forever), and in IE (it takes a *REALLY* long time loading, but eventually starts playing the movie again). In IE it seems not to be progressively downloading, while in Chrome it seems to be so, since it plays immediately when I carefully drag the seek bar).

My page's HTML code is:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/Scripts/MediaElement/mediaelementplayer.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/MediaElement/mediaelement-and-player.min.js"></script>

...

<video id="v1" src="/media/movies/20131201025101_E93D47344CA84A67BE4637ED9B5434D6/10.m4v" controls="controls" width="912" height="404"/>

<script>
  var player = new MediaElementPlayer('#v1', {startVolume: 0.8
  });
  player.play();
</script>
```

I then downloaded jPlayer's example video http://www.jplayer.org/video/m4v/Big_Buck_Bunny_Trailer.m4v. I tried it on my server with MediaElement and... it works fine!

Therefore, I come to the conclusion that the problem is in my file.

***MediaInfo*** reports the following:

```
General
Complete name                            : 12.m4v
Format                                   : MPEG-4
Format profile                           : Base Media / Version 2
Codec ID                                 : mp42
File size                                : 88.9 MiB
Duration                                 : 10mn 35s
Overall bit rate mode                    : Variable
Overall bit rate                         : 1 173 Kbps
Encoded date                             : UTC 2013-12-01 17:14:40
Tagged date                              : UTC 2013-12-01 17:16:07
Writing application                      : HandBrake 0.9.9 2013052900

Video
ID                                       : 1
Format                                   : AVC
Format/Info                              : Advanced Video Codec
Format profile                           : Baseline@L3.0
Format settings, CABAC                   : No
Format settings, ReFrames                : 3 frames
Codec ID                                 : avc1
Codec ID/Info                            : Advanced Video Coding
Duration                                 : 10mn 35s
Bit rate mode                            : Variable
Bit rate                                 : 1 000 Kbps
Width                                    : 512 pixels
Height                                   : 384 pixels
Display aspect ratio                     : 4:3
Frame rate mode                          : Constant
Frame rate                               : 25.000 fps
Color space                              : YUV
Chroma subsampling                       : 4:2:0
Bit depth                                : 8 bits
Scan type                                : Progressive
Bits/(Pixel*Frame)                       : 0.203
Stream size                              : 76.6 MiB (86%)
Writing library                          : x264 core 130 r2273 b3065e6
Encoding settings                        : cabac=0 / ref=3 / deblock=1:0:0 / analyse=0x1:0x111 / me=hex / subme=7 / psy=1 / psy_rd=1.00:0.00 / mixed_ref=1 / me_range=16 / chroma_me=1 / trellis=1 / 8x8dct=0 / cqm=0 / deadzone=21,11 / fast_pskip=1 / chroma_qp_offset=-2 / threads=6 / lookahead_threads=1 / sliced_threads=0 / nr=0 / decimate=1 / interlaced=0 / bluray_compat=0 / constrained_intra=0 / bframes=0 / weightp=0 / keyint=250 / keyint_min=25 / scenecut=40 / intra_refresh=0 / rc_lookahead=40 / rc=abr / mbtree=1 / bitrate=1000 / ratetol=1.0 / qcomp=0.60 / qpmin=0 / qpmax=69 / qpstep=4 / vbv_maxrate=10000 / vbv_bufsize=10000 / nal_hrd=none / ip_ratio=1.40 / aq=1:1.00
Encoded date                             : UTC 2013-12-01 17:14:40
Tagged date                              : UTC 2013-12-01 17:16:07
Color primaries                          : BT.601 NTSC
Transfer characteristics                 : BT.709
Matrix coefficients                      : BT.601

Audio
ID                                       : 2
Format                                   : AAC
Format/Info                              : Advanced Audio Codec
Format profile                           : LC
Codec ID                                 : 40
Duration                                 : 10mn 35s
Bit rate mode                            : Variable
Bit rate                                 : 160 Kbps
Maximum bit rate                         : 192 Kbps
Channel count                            : 2 channels
Channel positions                        : Front: L R
Sampling rate                            : 44.1 KHz
Compression mode                         : Lossy
Stream size                              : 12.1 MiB (14%)
Encoded date                             : UTC 2013-12-01 17:14:40
Tagged date                              : UTC 2013-12-01 17:16:06
```

It SEEMS to me very alike ***MediaInfo***'s report on jPlayer's example video (renamed to 11.m4v):

```
General
Complete name                            : 11.m4v
Format                                   : MPEG-4
Format profile                           : Base Media / Version 2
Codec ID                                 : mp42
File size                                : 3.87 MiB
Duration                                 : 33s 65ms
Overall bit rate mode                    : Variable
Overall bit rate                         : 983 Kbps
Encoded date                             : UTC 2011-08-30 14:11:40
Tagged date                              : UTC 2011-08-30 14:11:44
Writing application                      : HandBrake 0.9.5 2011010300

Video
ID                                       : 1
Format                                   : AVC
Format/Info                              : Advanced Video Codec
Format profile                           : Baseline@L3.0
Format settings, CABAC                   : No
Format settings, ReFrames                : 2 frames
Codec ID                                 : avc1
Codec ID/Info                            : Advanced Video Coding
Duration                                 : 32s 520ms
Bit rate mode                            : Variable
Bit rate                                 : 867 Kbps
Width                                    : 640 pixels
Height                                   : 360 pixels
Display aspect ratio                     : 16:9
Frame rate mode                          : Constant
Frame rate                               : 25.000 fps
Color space                              : YUV
Chroma subsampling                       : 4:2:0
Bit depth                                : 8 bits
Scan type                                : Progressive
Bits/(Pixel*Frame)                       : 0.150
Stream size                              : 3.36 MiB (87%)
Writing library                          : x264 core 112
Encoding settings                        : cabac=0 / ref=2 / deblock=1:0:0 / analyse=0x1:0x111 / me=hex / subme=6 / psy=1 / psy_rd=1.00:0.00 / mixed_ref=0 / me_range=16 / chroma_me=1 / trellis=0 / 8x8dct=0 / cqm=0 / deadzone=21,11 / fast_pskip=1 / chroma_qp_offset=-2 / threads=12 / sliced_threads=0 / nr=0 / decimate=1 / interlaced=0 / constrained_intra=0 / bframes=0 / weightp=0 / keyint=250 / keyint_min=25 / scenecut=40 / intra_refresh=0 / rc_lookahead=40 / rc=crf / mbtree=1 / crf=20.0 / qcomp=0.60 / qpmin=3 / qpmax=51 / qpstep=4 / ip_ratio=1.40 / aq=1:1.00
Encoded date                             : UTC 2011-08-30 14:11:40
Tagged date                              : UTC 2011-08-30 14:11:44
Color primaries                          : BT.601 NTSC
Transfer characteristics                 : BT.709
Matrix coefficients                      : BT.601

Audio
ID                                       : 2
Format                                   : AAC
Format/Info                              : Advanced Audio Codec
Format profile                           : LC
Codec ID                                 : 40
Duration                                 : 33s 65ms
Bit rate mode                            : Variable
Bit rate                                 : 128 Kbps
Maximum bit rate                         : 149 Kbps
Channel count                            : 2 channels
Channel positions                        : Front: L R
Sampling rate                            : 44.1 KHz
Compression mode                         : Lossy
Stream size                              : 515 KiB (13%)
Encoded date                             : UTC 2011-08-30 14:11:40
Tagged date                              : UTC 2011-08-30 14:11:44
```

Also, I have already moved the moov atom to the beginning of the file. This is ***AtomicParsley***'s report on my file:

```
Atom ftyp @ 0 of size: 28, ends @ 28
Atom moov @ 28 of size: 222456, ends @ 222484
     Atom mvhd @ 36 of size: 108, ends @ 144
     Atom iods @ 144 of size: 24, ends @ 168
     Atom trak @ 168 of size: 96599, ends @ 96767
         Atom tkhd @ 176 of size: 92, ends @ 268
         Atom mdia @ 268 of size: 96499, ends @ 96767
             Atom mdhd @ 276 of size: 32, ends @ 308
             Atom hdlr @ 308 of size: 33, ends @ 341
             Atom minf @ 341 of size: 96426, ends @ 96767
                 Atom vmhd @ 349 of size: 20, ends @ 369
                 Atom dinf @ 369 of size: 36, ends @ 405
                     Atom dref @ 377 of size: 28, ends @ 405
                 Atom stbl @ 405 of size: 96362, ends @ 96767
                     Atom stsd @ 413 of size: 170, ends @ 583
                         Atom avc1 @ 429 of size: 154, ends @ 583
                             Atom avcC @ 515 of size: 50, ends @ 565
                             Atom colr @ 565 of size: 18, ends @ 583                     ~
                     Atom stts @ 583 of size: 24, ends @ 607
                     Atom stsz @ 607 of size: 63588, ends @ 64195
                     Atom stsc @ 64195 of size: 28, ends @ 64223
                     Atom stco @ 64223 of size: 15908, ends @ 80131
                     Atom stss @ 80131 of size: 732, ends @ 80863
                     Atom sdtp @ 80863 of size: 15904, ends @ 96767
     Atom trak @ 96767 of size: 125606, ends @ 222373
         Atom tkhd @ 96775 of size: 92, ends @ 96867
         Atom mdia @ 96867 of size: 125484, ends @ 222351
             Atom mdhd @ 96875 of size: 32, ends @ 96907
             Atom hdlr @ 96907 of size: 33, ends @ 96940
             Atom minf @ 96940 of size: 125411, ends @ 222351
                 Atom smhd @ 96948 of size: 16, ends @ 96964
                 Atom dinf @ 96964 of size: 36, ends @ 97000
                     Atom dref @ 96972 of size: 28, ends @ 97000
                 Atom stbl @ 97000 of size: 125351, ends @ 222351
                     Atom stsd @ 97008 of size: 103, ends @ 97111
                         Atom mp4a @ 97024 of size: 87, ends @ 97111
                             Atom esds @ 97060 of size: 51, ends @ 97111
                     Atom stts @ 97111 of size: 24, ends @ 97135
                     Atom stsz @ 97135 of size: 109528, ends @ 206663
                     Atom stsc @ 206663 of size: 28, ends @ 206691
                     Atom stco @ 206691 of size: 15660, ends @ 222351
         Atom udta @ 222351 of size: 22, ends @ 222373
             Atom name @ 222359 of size: 14, ends @ 222373
     Atom udta @ 222373 of size: 111, ends @ 222484
         Atom meta @ 222381 of size: 103, ends @ 222484
             Atom hdlr @ 222393 of size: 33, ends @ 222426
             Atom ilst @ 222426 of size: 58, ends @ 222484
                 Atom ©too @ 222434 of size: 50, ends @ 222484
                     Atom data @ 222442 of size: 42, ends @ 222484
Atom mdat @ 222484 of size: 92990967, ends @ 93213451

 ~ denotes an unknown atom
------------------------------------------------------
Total size: 93213451 bytes; 49 atoms total. AtomicParsley version: 0.9.0 (utf16)
Media data: 92990967 bytes; 222484 bytes all other atoms (0.239% atom overhead).
Total free atom space: 0 bytes; 0.000% waste.
------------------------------------------------------
```

Again, it looks pretty similar to jPlayer's example file:

```
Atom ftyp @ 0 of size: 28, ends @ 28
Atom moov @ 28 of size: 12713, ends @ 12741
     Atom mvhd @ 36 of size: 108, ends @ 144
     Atom iods @ 144 of size: 24, ends @ 168
     Atom trak @ 168 of size: 5484, ends @ 5652
         Atom tkhd @ 176 of size: 92, ends @ 268
         Atom mdia @ 268 of size: 5384, ends @ 5652
             Atom mdhd @ 276 of size: 32, ends @ 308
             Atom hdlr @ 308 of size: 33, ends @ 341
             Atom minf @ 341 of size: 5311, ends @ 5652
                 Atom vmhd @ 349 of size: 20, ends @ 369
                 Atom dinf @ 369 of size: 36, ends @ 405
                     Atom dref @ 377 of size: 28, ends @ 405
                 Atom stbl @ 405 of size: 5247, ends @ 5652
                     Atom stsd @ 413 of size: 170, ends @ 583
                         Atom avc1 @ 429 of size: 154, ends @ 583
                             Atom avcC @ 515 of size: 50, ends @ 565
                             Atom colr @ 565 of size: 18, ends @ 583                     ~
                     Atom stts @ 583 of size: 24, ends @ 607
                     Atom stsz @ 607 of size: 3272, ends @ 3879
                     Atom stsc @ 3879 of size: 40, ends @ 3919
                     Atom stco @ 3919 of size: 832, ends @ 4751
                     Atom stss @ 4751 of size: 76, ends @ 4827
                     Atom sdtp @ 4827 of size: 825, ends @ 5652
     Atom trak @ 5652 of size: 6978, ends @ 12630
         Atom tkhd @ 5660 of size: 92, ends @ 5752
         Atom mdia @ 5752 of size: 6856, ends @ 12608
             Atom mdhd @ 5760 of size: 32, ends @ 5792
             Atom hdlr @ 5792 of size: 33, ends @ 5825
             Atom minf @ 5825 of size: 6783, ends @ 12608
                 Atom smhd @ 5833 of size: 16, ends @ 5849
                 Atom dinf @ 5849 of size: 36, ends @ 5885
                     Atom dref @ 5857 of size: 28, ends @ 5885
                 Atom stbl @ 5885 of size: 6723, ends @ 12608
                     Atom stsd @ 5893 of size: 103, ends @ 5996
                         Atom mp4a @ 5909 of size: 87, ends @ 5996
                             Atom esds @ 5945 of size: 51, ends @ 5996
                     Atom stts @ 5996 of size: 24, ends @ 6020
                     Atom stsz @ 6020 of size: 5716, ends @ 11736
                     Atom stsc @ 11736 of size: 40, ends @ 11776
                     Atom stco @ 11776 of size: 832, ends @ 12608
         Atom udta @ 12608 of size: 22, ends @ 12630
             Atom name @ 12616 of size: 14, ends @ 12630
     Atom udta @ 12630 of size: 111, ends @ 12741
         Atom meta @ 12638 of size: 103, ends @ 12741
             Atom hdlr @ 12650 of size: 33, ends @ 12683
             Atom ilst @ 12683 of size: 58, ends @ 12741
                 Atom ©too @ 12691 of size: 50, ends @ 12741
                     Atom data @ 12699 of size: 42, ends @ 12741
Atom mdat @ 12741 of size: 4050118, ends @ 4062859

 ~ denotes an unknown atom
------------------------------------------------------
Total size: 4062859 bytes; 49 atoms total. AtomicParsley version: 0.9.0 (utf16)
Media data: 4050118 bytes; 12741 bytes all other atoms (0.314% atom overhead).
Total free atom space: 0 bytes; 0.000% waste.
------------------------------------------------------
```

Despite the similarities, there's GOT to be something fundamentally different in the encoding of the two file above mentioned, because seeking on one of them ALWAYS WORKS, while seeking on the other ALWAYS FAILS.

That said, what can be wrong with my video file? How can I correct it (preferably using Handbrake (please note that MediaInfo reports that HandBrake was used to encode the file that works))?

Note: I checked my server's MIME types and turned off my HTTP GZIP compression.

Thanks in advance.

Dan

Answer (score 1):

Bit of a late answer, but it could be down to the server not accepting accept-ranges header information (the server can request just a part of the file).  See:

http://www.cyberciti.biz/cloud-computing/http-status-code-206-commad-line-test/